# Python Flask app.run process does not quit

Tags: python, flask

I have a Python and Flask script as follows:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/myroute")
def foo():
    # do something
    # copy json results into file **output.json**
    # return output.json
app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)
```

after running the app (flask run) I hit my url and get the results in output.json as my http response. However, after I try to stop the flask run with a ctrl-c or ctrl-z, my URL still returns the output.json file content.

I have cleared my browser cache.

I then deleted the output.json file on the server and ran the url. Surprisingly, I still get the output.json result but there is no output.json file created on the server. This means my Flask job did not run and some other task is returning output.json results cached on the server.

Can someone help me figure out what is going on and how to identify what task is responding with json results?

Edited:
I am using Linux Centos.
I do not have any web servers and no other components are running.
This is how I run my flask job:
    export FLASK_APP=myscript.py
    flask run

Comment: What OS and how are you running this script?

Comment: Ctrl-Z suggest UNIX like, no?

Comment: Are you running Flask out of the box as default? Or do you have other components at play here? I.e. an Nginx reverse web proxy or a Gunicorn uWSGI server running?

Comment: I edited the original post with answers.

Comment: I am only running Flask, no other components such as web or proxy server. Please see my original note for answers.

Comment: trying using a python virtual environment to isolate the problem